# Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT EXEC form not working with Powershell

Tags: powershell, docker

I have to following (simple) Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:latest
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
ENTRYPOINT ["Get-ChildItem ", "-Path", "'C:\Program Files\'"]
```

If I run the container. I get the following error:

> At line:1 char:77 + ... ference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; ["Get-Chi ...
>   +                                                                  ~
>   Missing type name after '['.
>   At line:1 char:93
>   + ...  $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; ["Get-ChildItem ", "-Path" ...
>   +                                                                 ~
>   Missing argument in parameter list.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
>      ception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingTypename

I also tried:

```
 ENTRYPOINT ["Get-ChildItem ", "-Path 'C:\Program Files\'"]
```

and got the same error.

If I use the shell form the ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:latest
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
ENTRYPOINT Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files\'
```

Everything works fine.

Can somebody tell me how to write this simple PS command in the "exec-form" when using ENTRYPOINT. I'm asking since [the docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) states that the "exec-form" is the preferred one.

Thx

Comment: Giving a brief read through, I think this is because the Shell form uses what's defined in SHELL (or the cmd /c default) and Exec form you need to explicitly call the executable `powershell.exe` in the command. Does `ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files\'"]` work?

Comment: This was the section of the reference that lead me to that conclusion: _The SHELL instruction allows the default shell used for the **shell form** of commands to be overridden._

Comment: Unfortunately,  I get the same error. If you are more interested in the problem I've uploaded the docker image and Dockerfile to: https://hub.docker.com/r/moerwald33/docker_powershell_exec_form/

Comment: I didn't have a chance to look at the actual container, but I think another thing is that some of the characters like \ need to be escaped when using the Exec form. e.g. `C:\Program Files` -> `C:\\Program Files`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the trailing space at the end of "Get-ChildItem "

Failing that, is it interpreting \' after Program Files as an escaped character ?